# jbogard/Respawn, how to reseed sql?

Tags: c#

Can't understand how to Reseed via Respawn. ReseedSql property is a private set.
How do I set this property? I don't see a constructor with parameters to set private setters.
Should I override the Checkpoint class?

```
public class Checkpoint
    {
        private GraphBuilder _graphBuilder;
        private IList<TemporalTable> _temporalTables = new List<TemporalTable>();

        public string[] TablesToIgnore { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] TablesToInclude { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] SchemasToInclude { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string[] SchemasToExclude { get; set; } = new string[0];
        public string DeleteSql { get; private set; }
        public string ReseedSql { get; private set; }
        public bool CheckTemporalTables { get; set; } = false;
        internal string DatabaseName { get; private set; }
        public bool WithReseed { get; set; } = false;
        public IDbAdapter DbAdapter { get; set; } = Respawn.DbAdapter.SqlServer;

        public int? CommandTimeout { get; set; }

        
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by reseed?

Answer (score 1):

If by reseed you mean reseting identity columns seed values during the reset, then you simply need to set Checkpoint.WithReseed to true.

See this [PR](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn/pull/40/files) and this [issue](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn/issues/38) for implementation details and discussion.

But if reseed means restoring data to its initial state instead of just deleting it, you might want to checkout the [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) library.